# Javascript based dynamic content using htmlUnit

Tags: java, javascript, htmlunit

I have been stuck in getting JavaScript based dynamic content using HtmlUnit. I am expecting to get (Signin, Registration html content) from the page. With the following code, I only get the static content.

I am new to HtmlUnit. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
String strURL = "https://www.checkmytrip.com" ;
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_31);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(60 * 1000);
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

HtmlPage myPage = ((HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(strURL));

String theContent = myPage.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
System.out.println(theContent);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two points:

1. You need to waitForBackgroundJavaScript() after you get the page, as hinted [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#AJAXDoesNotWork)
2. You should use myPage.asText() or .asXml() instead, because getWebResponse() returns the original content without JavaScript execution.

   ```
   String strURL = "https://www.checkmytrip.com" ;
   java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
   java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

   try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_31)) {
       webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

       HtmlPage myPage = ((HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(strURL));
       webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10 * 1000);

       String theContent = myPage.asXml();
       System.out.println(theContent);
   }
   ```