# Scraping mobile sites with HtmlUnit

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, htmlunit

I am scraping a mobile version site with Htmlunit. I think that this site generates part of its html with some scripts. I couldn´t parse the whole html of the site, only html that I think it is not generated dynamically. I am not sure if the way I set a mobile user Agent is corrector or if I am doing something wrong reading the page. I have tried the solutions posted on threads that explain the way to read dynamically generated sites so I don't know what could be the key to solve my problem so maybe the site doesn't generates part of its html dynamically

This is my code:

```
/* turn off annoying htmlunit warnings */
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

        final BrowserVersionBuilder myMobileExplorerBuilder = new BrowserVersion.BrowserVersionBuilder(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52);
        myMobileExplorerBuilder.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16");


        WebClient client = new WebClient(myMobileExplorerBuilder.build());  
        client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);  
        client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        client.getOptions().setActiveXNative(true);

        String url = "https://mobile.bet365.es/";

        HtmlPage page = client.getPage(url);

        System.out.println(page.getBody().asXml());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript based dynamic content using htmlUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342087/javascript-based-dynamic-content-using-htmlunit)

Comment: you can also call the direct get request to parse data. That's the route I would do personally

Comment: How can I know exactly which is the direct get request that loads that data? I tried the solutions explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342087/javascript-based-dynamic-content-using-htmlunit  but doesn't work in my case

Comment: If you are hunting for problems it might be a good start to no longer suppress all log output. Maybe there is a hint for you....